# php laravel 7 blade template form won't submit when class applied to inputs

Tags: php, html, laravel, forms

```
@extends('layouts.head')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron" style="margin: 1.2rem auto 0 auto; text-align: center; width:30rem;">
        <div>
            <h1>문의하기</h1>
        </div>
        <form method="POST" action="/admin" name="Form">
            @csrf
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="title" placeholder="제목">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" name="description" placeholder="내용" rows="10"></textarea>    
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="form-control" type="submit" value="Submit">submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

So when I apply these classes with bootstrap, the form won't submit and it will return back to the site without saving inputs into database. When I remove all the classes, it will submit, I have no idea why it happens. I looked up google but still no luck, any help will be appreciated, and these are the route and controller.

```
Route::post('/admin','PostsController@store');
Route::get('/post/create','PostsController@create');


public function create()
    {
        return view('posts.create');
    }


public function store(Request $request) {
        Post::create(request()->validate([
            'title' => ['required','min:3'],
            'description' => ['required','min:3']
        ]));
        return redirect('/')->with('message', 'Task was successful!');
        }
```

Comment: what is file name and share you routes also ?

Comment: @RishiRaut updated the routes and the controller, what file names are you asking?

Comment: did you debug by putting `return dd($request->all())` as first line inside `store` function  ?

Comment: i did that and it works fine with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a validation error. You should really be displaying validation errors back to your form, otherwise you are blindly testing. Add the `@error` directives to your code to see if it's returning validation errors to your client:

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron" style="margin: 1.2rem auto 0 auto; text-align: center; width:30rem;">
            <div>
                <h1>문의하기</h1>
            </div>
            <form method="POST" action="/admin" name="Form">
                @csrf
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="title" placeholder="제목">
                </div>
                @error('title')
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
                @enderror
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="description" placeholder="내용" rows="10"></textarea>    
                </div>
                @error('description')
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
                @enderror
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="form-control" type="submit" value="Submit">submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: somehow your code just works, i don't know why though, it wont even throw an error, weird...

Answer (score 0):

You may be encountering a validation issue with your min. You can see the min description in the doc:

> For string data, value corresponds to the number of characters. For
>   numeric data, value corresponds to a given integer value (the
>   attribute must also have the numeric or integer rule). For an array,
>   size corresponds to the count of the array.

On a side note, it is much more readable to put your `validate()` outside of your `Create`

```
    public function store(Request $request) {
        $request->validate([
            'title' => ['required','min:3'],
            'description' => ['required','min:3']
        ]);

        Post::create([
            $request->get('title'),
            $request->get('description'),
        ]);

        return redirect('/')->with('message', 'Task was successful!');
    }
```

Comment: Technically he is doing it a valid way, although not ideal. It correctly validates the input before creating the record. This looks like some external or small issue elsewhere.

Comment: @Nathan I believe that the `validate()` function returns `true` if valid which wouldn't work with `Create`

Comment: `Validate()` returns the validated data, see https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic  Maybe you're confusing it with a validator instance, that returns false if the rule set fails?

Comment: I'm confused - in the doc I can just see `our controller will continue executing normally.` but if I go digging into the framework code it seems that it is indeed returning an array of the validated request

Comment: nevermind, you are right @Nathan - just tried it in one of my `validate` function - it will indeed work but won't be very much readable 